# HTML5 тег <label> вне <form>

Tags: html5, css3

1. Можно ли использовать html5 тег `<label>` вне `<form>` ?
2. Как задать нижний маргин для сайта ? После `html,body{height:100%}` сайт приклеился к низу

Comment: 1.)Можно ли использовать html5 тег <label> вне <form> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Почему бы и нет?
2. Недостаточно данных для ответа. Сайт - это как бы общее название ресурсов, `margin` может быть только у элементов DOM.